# Request.QueryString.get password

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to get a string from

http://localhost:4745/(S(wqepemuj23hohb45xjvy4urb))/JSONObject.aspx?method=GetMyID&user=PUN001&pwd=SaiRam#01

in this username is PUN001 & password is SaiRam#01 and method is GetMyID

```
password = Request.QueryString.Get("pwd").ToString();
```

this is getting only the value `SaiRam` it is not taking `#01`, It is not taking the complete string.

please help me on this

Comment: first of all,its very bad practice to send data like Password in QueryString,another thing your browser will automatic chat to "%23"  if you have used # in your query string (ref : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp),you can use session for your password.

Comment: Actually im using this for calling data for mobile devices. I guess it is not converting it to %23. Im not getting any problem with other special characters

Comment: how can i get the complete values on the URL

Comment: did you try below answer ?

Comment: HttpUtility.UrlEncode("pwd#01"); this is hardcoded right

Comment: If i get to take the value like this then problem is solved

Comment: i think i got solution for you. check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Every thing after # tag consider client side. so you may handle it on the client side or use this method to get string accurately by using url encoding and decoding

```
  var abc = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("pwd#01");
    var abc1 = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(abc);
```

Comment: How to get that pwd#01 as i cant hardcode anything like this

Answer (score 0):

As there is value in URL,i would like to recommended EscapeUriString()

Try something like this,

```
password =  Uri.EscapeUriString(Request.QueryString.Get("pwd").ToString());
```

Here EscapeUriString will return same value even if there is special character has been used.

Comment: No this also returns till # key. Using this it always stop at  #